# Hard time finding Python-Numpy deg2rad function

Tags: python, numpy, vector, scipy, degrees

Title says it all, I somehow can not find that function. Obviously it's inside the Numpy package (numpy.core.umath.deg2rad) and I've tried importing it but to no avail. Anyone care to chime in?

- import numpy as np - np.deg2rad doesn't even show up
- from numpy import* - umath.deg2rad shows up, but it raises an error, ''name 'umath' is not defined''

Comment: I can find it using `np.deg2rad()`. What version of Numpy are you using?

Comment: @Ffisegydd I'm using version 1.8. I skimmed the Numpy reference guide and it says that numpy.deg2rad should be sufficient :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from numpy.core.umath import deg2rad
# then
deg2rad(...)
```

Or

```
import numpy as np
np.core.umath.deg2rad(...)
```

Comment: thank you, now it works :) But still, how come that numpy.deg2rad isn't sufficient?

Comment: Because deg2rad is in a submodule

Comment: @MrE This works in numpy 1.7.1 and numpy 1.8 without as simply `np.deg2rad` on my machines. This suggest something else is going on.

Comment: @Ophion oh yeah you are right it should be available imported as `np.deg2rad` according to the docs, and it does work on my machine. I wonder what the real problem is.

Comment: deg2rad is also in the main numpy namespace. Importing stuff directly from private, undocumented, submodules like numpy.core.umath is in general not recommended.